# Xamarin.forms swipeable background, carousel style navigation

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to create a carousel background in Xamarin. I already know about [this](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3AXamarin.Forms.CarouselPage), but it seems that is only used to replace the entire page with another page. What I would like to do is keep some UI overlay, buttons and text in the top and bottom of the page, but I would like to change the entire background when the user swipes (including the horizontal slide animation). As far as I understand, only one page can be visible at a time, meaning that I cannot display a transparent page on top of another page and then only animate the last page. It therefore seems that my goal is not reachable using the carousel that I linked to. What else could be done?

I am using Xamarin.forms and developing for iOS and Android.

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately for most of Xamarin.Forms you will need to create Custom Renderers for everything non-standard (and even some standard stuff).  See http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/

Answer (score 0):

You can use plugins are available for Carousel View. Carousel Page is used for swiping all page. While use of Carousel View will just scroll only particular potion of page.

Nuget List :

- [Plugin 1](https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView)
- [Plugin 2](https://github.com/chrisriesgo/xamarin-forms-carouselview)
- [Sample Example](https://blog.xamarin.com/flip-through-items-with-xamarin-forms-carouselview/)